# Nodemon command not found issue

Tags: node.js, windows, nodemon

I recently update my node.js version and npm and now I am getting a error:
$ nodemon
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found;

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, I am pretty new to using nodemon and node. I have searched the previous questions and tried updating my Path variables but so far nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed nodemon globally or just installed it ? If not , try npm install -g nodemon to install it globally.

Answer (score 0):

If uninstalling and then reinstalling of nodemon module did not work, please try `npx nodemon script.js` . I tried it in my VS Code Git Bash terminal and found it working.

Comment: Please find out about proper formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help